# Laravel 5 : русифицировать дату

Tags: laravel, locale

Всем привет,
В laravel 5.5  нужно русифицировать дату и нагуглил способ :

```
echo '<pre>$a::' . print_r($a, true) . '</pre>';


setlocale(LC_TIME, 'ru');
date_default_timezone_set('CET');
Carbon::setLocale('ru');


echo '<pre>$format::'.print_r($format,true).'</pre>';
$b = $a->format($format);
echo '<pre>$b::'.print_r($b,true).'</pre>';
```

С выводом:

```
$a::Carbon\Carbon Object
(
    [date] => 2017-11-24 16:32:50.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => CET
)
$format::j F, Y g:i A$b::24 November, 2017 4:32 PM
```

То есть русифиция не сработала...

также строки

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'ru');
    date_default_timezone_set('CET');
    Carbon::setLocale('ru');
```

Я вставлял в app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php:

```
public function boot()
{ 
    setlocale(LC_TIME, 'ru');
    date_default_timezone_set('CET');
    Carbon::setLocale('ru');
```

С тем же результатом. А как правильно?

Спасибо!

Comment: Было бы логично использовать словари для локализации. Почитайте о локализации в ларавел.

Comment: я тут https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/localization читал и о локализации даты не нашел
Ссылку дайте, пожалуйста...

Answer (score 12):

Если вам нужно локализация даты, которая выводится через метод `format`, используйте PHP функцию [setLocale()](http://www.php.net/setlocale):

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'ru_RU.UTF-8');
```

Так же замените метод `format` на `formatLocalized`, и так же учтите что метод `formatLocalized` использует функцию [strftime()](http://www.php.net/strftime) которая использует другие параметры, так что методы `format` нужно будет переписать под новые, список параметров найдете в описании функции.

Приведу пример того что написал выше:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но есть ещё один метод `diffForHumans` который выводит дату в следующем виде:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для её локализации необходимо задать локаль в самом `Carbon` через метод `setLocale`:

```
Carbon::setLocale('ru');
```

Лучше вынести этот параметр в конфиг (точнее он там уже есть) и использовать его:

```
Carbon::setLocale(config('app.locale'));
```

Приведу пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так получается что для разных методов разные подходы, так устроена библиотека `Carbon`.

Устанавливать всё это нужно в момент запуска ядра, для этого нужно добавить это в метод `boot` сервис провайдера, к примеру `AppServiceProvider`:

```
public function boot()
{
    setlocale(LC_TIME, 'ru_RU.UTF-8');
    Carbon::setLocale(config('app.locale'));
}
```

Comment: Yaroslav Molchan,
Спасибо, я старался следовать за вашими инструкциями, но лейблы даты все равно выводит на английском...
Может ли это быть привязано к настройкам в php.ini или установкам каких-либо доп пакетов ?

Comment: @mstdmstd возможно в setLocale вам поможет указать setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.UTF-8');, но я это делал на ubuntu, на windows по другому локаль ставиться, все примеры выполнял сразу же в консоли Ubuntu и по примерам видно что всё отработало.

Comment: У меня также ubuntu и я делал setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.UTF-8'); А дополнительные пакеты там никакие не нужны ?

Comment: Локаль нужно чтобы была ru_RU.UTF-8, проверить можно командой `locale -a`, если её нет - установите

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Comment: И еще возник насчет Устанавливать всё это нужно в момент запуска ядра например в AppServiceProvider как упомянуто выше
Но текущая локаль хранится в сессии а в методе boot AppServiceProvider-а данные сесси недоступны...
Посоветуйте, где еще можно инициализтровать 1 раз в приложении ?

Comment: @mstdmstd "хранится в сессии а в методе boot AppServiceProvider-а данные сесси недоступны." вообще не понял о чем речь.

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте, какие локали поддерживаются:

```
$ locale -a
```

Добавьте локали, которые вы хотите (например ru):

```
$ sudo locale-gen ru_RU
$ sudo locale-gen ru_RU.UTF-8
```

Запустите эту команду обновления:

```
$ sudo update-locale
```

Обязательно сделайте рестарт php, после изменений setlocale например:

```
$ sudo service php8.0-fpm restart
```